# How do you convert a string to ASCII Binary?

Tags: c#, binary, unity-ui

I'm working on a unity project and need to convert an string input by the user to ASCII binary. To my knowledge this is the way to do that:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class Binary : MonoBehaviour
{

    public string MatchNumber;
    public string BinaryMatchNumber;
    public TMP_InputField MatchNumberField;
    public Button Submit;

    void Start () {
        Button btnSubmit = Submit.GetComponent<Button>();
        btnSubmit.onClick.AddListener(UpdateMatchNumber);
    }

    void UpdateMatchNumber(string[] args)
    {   MatchNumber = MatchNumberField.text.ToString();
        byte[] asciiBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(MatchNumber);
        string BinaryMatchNumber = "";
        foreach (byte b in asciiBytes) {
            BinaryMatchNumber += MatchNumber.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
        }
        Debug.Log(BinaryMatchNumber);
    }
}
```

Unity console then throws the errors:

> Assets\Scripts\Binary.cs(17,39): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'UnityAction'

and

> Assets\Scripts\Binary.cs(25,46): error CS1501: No overload for method 'ToString' takes 2 arguments.

I've googled these errors and have been unable to find a solution that works and fixes it. To my understanding, it should just print the text in binary in the console, but it’s clearly not working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this statement: `MatchNumber.ToString(b, 2)`, which is attempting to convert `MatchNumber` (which is already a string) to a string, using an invalid syntax. `No overload for method 'ToString' takes 2 arguments`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message is quite clear. `string` does not have any method with the signature `ToString(byte, int)`. It does not have any `ToString` method with two arguments at all.

If you want to print the string as ascii bytes you could use string.Join

```
Debug.Log(string.Join(asciiBytes, ", "));
```

Should print a string like

```
42, 94, 24
```

and so on. Note that it is more common to [print bytes as hex values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa) than numerical values.